# Aren't Graphics/JPanel dimensions measured in pixels?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

When I draw [`drawRect(x, y, width, height)`] a rectangle on an JPanel inside a JFrame, that has a width of e.g. 500, it is actually wider than 500 Pixels on my Screen. How is this measured?

Whilst messing around with a drawing Rectangles on an JPanel and the size of the JFrame around this, i recognized, that 500 "width" are different things, when it comes to JFrame and JPanel.
A JFrame that is created with a width of 1920 Pixels is exactly 1920 Pixels wide, means, as wide as my screen (1920x1080).
If i draw a rectangle with a width of 1920 on a JPanel, that is inside the JFrame, it extends my screen by exactly 385 Pixels. Respectively: a drawn rectangle as wide as my screen needs a width of 1535.

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setSize(1920,1080);     //Window as wide as the screen
        window.add(new Canvas());
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setVisible(true);

    }

}

public class Canvas extends JPanel {

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, 1920, 500); //Paints a rectangle on the JPanel

    }
}
```

The window that opens is exactly as wide as my screen, but the rectangle inside extends it.
If I change the width of the rectangle to 1535 [`drawRect(0, 0, 1535, 500)`], it is as wide as the JFrame/screen. Why is that?

Edit: Since the Windows 10 Frame has no decorations at the side, just the standard menu-bar on top, I don't think this is the problem (as far as I understand decorations).

Comment: I can't test right now, but you're calling `super.paintComponentS(g);` and not `super.paintComponent(g);` (Note the `S`).

Comment: @Frakcool Thanks! That was a typo, I corrected it. But regarding this very problem, it makes no difference.

Comment: @SDJ I already read about the decorations (I believe exactly this post). But the Windows 10 frame doesn't have any decorations to the side.

Comment: @SDJ Yes, I see that now, but the rectangle extends the screen by 385 Pixels. That's slightly more than the 2*8 Insets.

Answer (score 1):

**The short answer**: Yes they are.

**The explanation**: Let us look deeper!

Running Java Swing on MacOS (tested with Metal LAF), the JFrame has insets of zero for left and right.  This is similar to rendering for certain themes on Windows 10.  I have included code below; the gap between the content pane and the panel's fill rectangle should remain 8 pixels.  When the program is running, resize it, and check for yourself.  Feel free to comment if this is not the behaviour you experience.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        final String name;
        name = javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel.class.getName();
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(name);
        }
        catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        createAndShowWindow();
    });
}

private static void createAndShowWindow() {
    final int width = 1920;
    final int height = 800;
    final int padding = 8;

    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    window.setTitle("Hello World.");
    window.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    window.setSize(width, height);     //Window as wide as the screen
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(padding);
    window.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    window.pack();
    window.setVisible(true);

    System.out.println("w: " + window.getSize());
    System.out.println("c: " + window.getContentPane().getSize());
    System.out.println("p: " + canvas.getSize());
    System.out.println("i: " + window.getInsets());
}

public static class Canvas extends JPanel {

    private final int padding;

    public Canvas(int padding) {
        this.padding = padding;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(new Color(180, 120, 16));
        //Paints a rectangle on the JPanel
        int x = padding;
        int y = padding;
        int w = getWidth() - 2 * padding;
        int h = getHeight() - 2 * padding;
        g.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
    }
}
```

Comment: The window that opens looks exactly as you described, full-screen-wide and a orange rectangle with 8 pixel gap at each side. But the output from the console confuses me: 
w: java.awt.Dimension[width=1554,height=800]
c: java.awt.Dimension[width=1906,height=763]
p: java.awt.Dimension[width=1906,height=763]
i: java.awt.Insets[top=30,left=7,bottom=7,right=7]
Why is the content pane now wider than the frame? And why does it tell the frame is significantly smaller than my screen?

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  Your results explain why you are confused about whether or not JSwing is using pixels.  With the data you have provided, I am also baffled.  My suggestion is to make some alterations to the code and see if you can figure this out.  It does appear to be an issue specific to the machine/operating system/software you are running.  If you discover something, let us know!